# 400 bad request for rest application/json

Tags: java, web-services, rest, webservice-client

Am developing simple rest webservices with jersey frame work. Written @POST method which consumes and produces {`MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}. Using chrome POSTMAN rest client to invoke the web services. Webservices is working as expected for below application/json request

```
{
  "author": "vijay",
  "created": "2016-10-28T14:55:55.273+05:37",
  "message": "RestServicedsfdsfsdfsdf"
}
```

there are no compilation errors in the code.

Message Resource:

```
import java.util.List;    
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {
    MessageService msgService = new MessageService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        return msgService.getAllMessages();
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    public Message getMessage(@PathParam("messageId")long messageId) {
        return msgService.getMessage(messageId);
    }
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        return msgService.addMessage(message);
    }
    @PUT
    @Path("/{messageId}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message updateMesage(@PathParam ("messageId") long id, Message message) {
        message.setId(id);
        return msgService.updateMessage(message);
    }

}
```

Message Service:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MessageService {

    private Map<Long, Message> messages = MesaageDataBase.getMessages();

    public MessageService() {
        messages.put(1L, new Message(1232, "RestService", "vijay"));
        messages.put(2L, new Message(1233, "RestServiceClient", "Ashok"));
    }

    public List<Message> getAllMessages() {

        return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
    }

    public Message getMessage(long id) {
        return messages.get(id);
    }

    public Message addMessage(Message message) {
        message.setId(messages.size() +1);
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message updateMessage(Message message) {
        if(message.getId() <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        messages.put(message.getId(), message);
        return message;
    }

    public Message removeMessage(Long id) {
        return messages.remove(id);
    }

}
```

Consume input data i added attachment please find.
[image: i give json input to post request]
Below is the error am getting in the chrome POSTMAN client:
[image]

Body of response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 - Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Bad Request</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.42</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your content type html? shouldn't it be application/json?

Comment: What's the body of the response? There should be an error message there.

Comment: contenet type also application/json

Comment: What's in the Headers tab of your post?

Comment: Headers tab having Content-Type=application/json

Comment: Can you add Message class in your question? It might be that the request JSON is not being correctly parsed to Message object maybe because "created" field which would be a date. Are you using jackson?